# What's with the IQ chart in Idiocracy?

Tags: idiocracy

In Idiocracy, they show an average IQ chart that is declining over the next few centuries. Now, anyone who's studied IQ knows that's nonsense. The average IQ of a population is *by definition* **100**. So, is this merely an instance of inadequate research by the writers, or is there an actual meaning to that chart?

Comment: Just assume that they are comparing the IQ average over time against the average at its maximum point in human history.  The same way people compare money over time by correcting for inflation.

Comment: I would think that it's more like they aren't even comparing them it's just a statistic that shows the average IQ of the population at a starting point X and showing how the average IQ of that population declined over the years, much like the graph I provided in my answer.

Comment: 100 is the median IQ of the norming sample group, [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient). If you don't update the sample group, you would be comparing to a fixed population in a fixed point in time. Doing it that way you can very well have declining IQ and that would be what I think the movie was about. That would be a way to visualize that the population is getting dumber.

Comment: Average (mean, not median) is something like 110 or 120 now, isn't it?

Comment: The [Flynn effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flynn_effect) seems relevant. Many people, including myself, are very surprised that the "raw" scores on IQ tests are actually trending *up*.

Comment: I would imagine that at some point, people forgot how to normalize IQ scores.

Comment: @KSmarts as I said in response to other answers, if they stopped normalizing, the raw scores would be meaningless. We know the tests weren't the same because some sample questions were given.

Comment: In Kornbluth's story The Marching Morons IIRC car speedometers were incorrectly calibrated to make it seem like cars were moving much faster than they were -- I would guess that to make people feel better about themselves, IQ scores were be changed so that the new normal was, say, 130 -- sort of like grade inflation.

Answer (score 24):

It's a comedy.

A joke.

Don't think too hard about a future where populations basically use a Gatorade-equivalent to water plants. It's merely a representation that people are stupid.

Even following internal logic, they'd be stupid enough to forget to (or even *how to*) calculate accurate median or general averages.

Comment: The smart people would know that the average IQ of the population would decline... It's literally just a chart showing the combined IQs of the people in the country divided by the number of people, if the average is declining that means that a majority of the people's IQ is getting lower..

Comment: So you're differentiating between the median and the mean? Everyone could be geniuses, and have an average IQ of 50 then (e.g. if 50% of people are *all* the same smart and everyone else is at around 0) however it **cannot** get lower than **50** then.

Comment: Go into a median calculator... Use a sample of the IQs of people in Idiocracy with low IQs... Use a sample size of let's say 10.  If 6 people have IQs of 50, 2 of 60, 1 of 70, and 1 of 100... The median is 50.

Comment: Anyway I was literally just saying that the chart depicts the declining IQ of the population as a whole.  The idea of the average IQ being 100 by definition has nothing to do with the chart...

Comment: Hmmm, tautology? If (as an alternative example) your sample is of 10 people, 6 of whom have an IQ of 6, 2 of 10, 1 of 20, and 1 of 30 ...what's the median IQ then (assuming a representative sample)?

Comment: THIS JUST IN: "Guy who made Beavis and Butthead may have made a comedy movie not 100% scientifically sound. We now return you to insanity."

Comment: Matt Median of that would be 6..

Comment: "If you're wondering how he eats and breathes
and other science facts (la la la),
then repeat to yourself, "It's just a show,
I should really just relax
for M̶y̶s̶t̶e̶r̶y̶ ̶S̶c̶i̶e̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶T̶h̶e̶a̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶3̶0̶0̶0̶!  IDIOCRACY"

Comment: **Don't think too hard** If I wanted not to think too hard, I would've watched the Oscar winning **ass**.

Comment: @Matt:  Median - [6 6 6 6 6 6 10 10 20 30][length / 2] = 6, Mean - ((6 * 6) + (2 * 10) + 20 + 30) / 10 = 10.6

Comment: @DoctorWho22, The scenario I outlined CANNOT EXIST. That may be the median OF THOSE NUMBERS but the very definition of IQ is that the score obtained by the majority of the population is an IQ of 100. The standard IQ test is given to a representative sample, and the score that most of the subjects make on that test IS an IQ of 100... period. If 100 years later, MOST of the subjects got a DIFFERENT score THAT would now be an IQ of 100. 100 is BY DEFINITION the most common level of intelligence. 100 is the top of the bell curve. If the top of the bell curve moves, "100" follows it.

Comment: Problem is that they are representing that the average IQ declining from what we know as the norm.... A chart that depicts the average IQ of a current population (by actually taking all people's IQ and dividing it by the population) will result in number X... That number does not HAVE to be 100.... Look at the chart in my answer.. It's similar to that...

Comment: Essentially we are comparing the IQ of what we consider the norm (IQ norm currently being between around 90 to 100) vs what the current population of the Earth is in the movie as time progresses... They are not changing it, hell I wouldn't even think that they would know how to change mathematical formulas...

Comment: @DoctorWho22 If they weren't changing it, they'd have to use the same questions as us. Raw scores are meaningless on different tests.

Comment: **If someone leaves two comments, and then leaves another one, how many comments did they leave?**

Comment: They are simply showing the decline in IQ from how we see it... The chart i have on my answer shows the same thing... and remember how I explained it as well... If I took the IQs of what people have in a neighborhood in over a 10 year period, the IQ test and raw score we have doesn't change but the chart would show (if there was a decrease) that the neighborhood showed a decrease in the average IQ of the sample...  They are just simply extrapolating the decrease in IQ from our standards over a course of a few centuries

Comment: a similar sort of silliness about IQ is that they talk about a bright kid who "at age 10 *already* has an IQ of 150"

Answer (score 6):

That's one of the key differences between a scientific paper (where exactly correct use of scientific terms and concepts are important) and a work of art (which has no such restrictions).

The main theme of the movie is "What would happen if humans were gradually becoming less intelligent?" (the use of 'what...if' being a common meme in science fiction). How is this concept going to be conveyed to the audience? A graph shows a decline in some measure of intelligence. Is it scientifically accurate or correct? Perhaps not. Is it effective in conveying an important concept to the audience? Yes.

On the other hand, one could argue that the *population* over which the median is being calculated is *every person who every lived* and not just *every person who is alive now*. In that case, the average IQ of those who are alive now could be gradually declining.

Comment: No, either way the median would be 100.

Comment: The median of the entire population (all people who ever lived) is a constant 100. The median of a subsample (people currently living) could be less.

Comment: Exactly if you take the median from the current population in IQ after the time jump then it would be less than 100...

Comment: @DoctorWho22 They can't be doing that because the questions have changed.

Comment: That has nothing to do with recording a new median given the IQs of the current population in the movie...  You are stuck on the notion that just because the raw median score for our current IQ tests is 100, that the average IQ of the world is actually 100...  The median raw score of 100 will stay that way if they use our methods of testing IQs... I can't stress enough that they are using a chart in the movie that depicts the decline of the average IQ of the human population "as time progresses" aka from starting point A.... to Ending point B (Centuries) in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you're thinking of IQ Tests representing the median raw score as 100 as an average like in the Wechsler Intelligence Scales.

As stated in the [IQ Classification Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IQ_classification):

> The Wechsler intelligence scales were originally developed from earlier
>   intelligence scales by David Wechsler. The first Wechsler test
>   published was the Wechsler-Bellevue Scale in 1939. The Wechsler IQ
>   tests for children and for adults are the most frequently used
>   individual IQ tests in the English-speaking world and in their
>   translated versions are perhaps the most widely used IQ tests
>   worldwide. The Wechsler tests have long been regarded as the "gold
>   standard" in IQ testing. The Wechsler Adult Intelligence
>   Scale—Fourth Edition (WAIS–IV) was published in 2008 by Psychological
>   Corporation. The Wechsler Intelligence Scale for Children—Fourth
>   Edition (WISC–IV) was published in 2003 by Psychological Corporation,
>   and the Wechsler Preschool and Primary Scale of Intelligence—Fourth
>   Edition (WPPSI–IV) was published in 2012 by Psychological Corporation.
>   Like all current IQ tests, the Wechsler tests report a "deviation IQ"
>   as the standard score for the full-scale IQ, with the norming sample
>   median raw score defined as IQ 100 and a score one standard deviation
>   higher defined as IQ 115 (and one deviation lower defined as IQ 85).

When they say that the average IQ of the population declined they are representing that the median score of the entire population was declining.

There is a website that shows the countries with the lowest average IQ of a population here

http://www.statisticbrain.com/countries-with-the-highest-lowest-average-iq/

For example

Equatorial Guinea's population has an average IQ of 59, while Ethopia has one of 63, which is well below 100.

Here's a real life chart too from

http://www.w-uh.com/posts/030831-IQ_and_populations.html

It states

> As you can see, in a 100 year period the world's average IQ will have
>   dropped from 92 to 86, a change of 6%.  That is pretty darn
>   significant.  And all because of differential population growth.

[image]

Comment: But the median score *by definition* is **100**

Comment: If the entire population of a country has low IQ the median will be lower as well...

Comment: For one country, perhaps, but for the world, it will always average 100.

Comment: It's only 100 by definition using the common IQ tests that we have currently... If a country is slowly getting dumber and the people are getting really dumb then do you really want to be called stupid?  Not that I think they'd care but they'd probably change the IQ standards in that said country to begin with.

Comment: According to that logic my question is even *stronger*, no?

Comment: Read the part where it says "with the norming sample median raw score defined as IQ 100"... Technically the norming sample median in Idiocracy would not be 100.

Comment: In Idiocracy they **would** score less than 100. You **do** realize it's a comedy and satire on declining educational standards, right? It's not a fracking documentary (yet).

Comment: Of course they would score less than 100, their IQ is less than the average IQ using our standards.  Just like another Countries average IQ is lower as well.  They were simply showing the the overall average of the IQ of people in the country was declining, not that our current standards of what we consider IQ average was changing.

Comment: I hope it's not this question that leads to our future of stupidity. I couldn't handle that level of META right now...

Comment: It's funny I found a real life chart too...

Comment: So the average IQ of the world is 100?  Seems like the chart and data show otherwise lol

Comment: WHOA! "A real life chart." I hope that chart applies to "fake life" like in the fake world in the fictional movie. :)

Comment: That chart is wrong by definition. Whoever wrote that article obviously doesn't know what IQ means and how it is calculated.

Comment: So if I actually calculated the average IQ of my neighborhood, then did it each year for 10 years and created a chart showing so... If the average IQ of the people in the neighborhood is let's say 98 and declines 5% in the 10 year span that's wrong by definition?  No it's an accurate chart, but your just failing to realize that the IQ standard has nothing to do with the data being represented... It's simply the average IQ (the entire population's IQs added up and then divided by the population) of a particular place.

Comment: If you're doing it for your neighborhood, then it might be right, but that chart is measuring *world IQ*, which makes it wrong.

Comment: The world's average IQ isn't exactly 100... As I stated the median sample raw score is defined by an arbitrary number... It doesn't mean that the world's average IQ is exactly 100...

Comment: If you were to take all the IQs of the entire world and then divide that by the population I can guarantee you that it will not be 100...  It might actually be a few off the only reason they use 100 as the number is to make calculations easier for standard deviations... For instance if you take the first 24 of the list from countries with highest iq... you'll get an average of 100.8  but if you take the top 10  lowest IQ from the same list the average is about 66.5  That's a very large gap...

Answer (score 2):

As the original question says, IQ scores are by definition normalized to have mean 100.
Interestingly, if you don't renormalize but grade current students by old standards, IQ scores appear to be rising. This is known as the [Flynn effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flynn_effect).

Comment: And reversing it, in Idiocracy, they probably never did re-normalize it.  Hence, dropping.

Comment: @Izkata They *must* have re-normalized it, otherwise they would have the same questions as our test.

Comment: @ike That is not correct. They could have just calibrated the new test to have (on average) the same results as the old one.

Comment: @Erik if they did, then the IQ levels would have stayed the same. What you're describing is exactly what normalizing is.

Comment: @ike that does not mean that the chart was normalized

Comment: @ike Also, they may have normalised it in, let's say 2100, then it continues to decline afterwards. The chart, however, compares IQ corrected for normalisation.

Comment: The effect has actually reversed in the last 30 years.