# Who are the smartest 5 people (human) in the Marvel Universe?

Tags: marvel

Who are the smartest 5 people (human) in the Marvel Universe?

There seem to be several kinds of smart.

Being the go-to specialist in a single field for example (Banner), or having vast uncommon knowledge (Doom).

Also when other geniuses are in a pickle and  they think to refer a situation to you, or mention your name, then it seems you are indeed top of the class.

There might be other Good metrics, what do you think?

Here's my pick:

1. Doctor Doom
2. Henry Pym
3. Bruce Banner
4. Tony Stark
5. Reed Richards

I would add Professor X to this list ... but i think these 5 are in a class of their own.

Also, this seems a lot easier to answer for the DC Universe.

Comment: you need to come up with your metric before asking the question.

Comment: point taken, see my edit

Comment: i commented after your edit. you need to tell *us* what the metric is. if you want help with that, you can jump into chat and i'm sure some people would be happy to help you hash it out. until then, this is too broad/unclear and primarily opinion based.

Comment: Also, it's [not so clear in DC](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14652/5184). And in case you're thinking of using IQ as your metric, be aware we've already had [a huge argument over whether IQ can/should be used to judge intelligence](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/48241/5184)

Comment: ah, i missed that discussion thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I'm assuming there will actually be a metric that can answer this canonically. I know the Marvel website has "power scores" which include intelligence

Comment: Wouldn't all the answers be non-earth higher beings like Yahweh and the like? You should change the question to "smartest humans" or something like that.

Comment: Also you probably want the marvel universe at large, not the cinematic one.

Comment: yeah i guess human and Marvel U

Comment: In Ultimate Spider-man: Web Warriors it's said that Leader, MODOK, and Amadeus Cho are the 5th, 6th, and 7th smartest people on the planet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually surprisingly easy to answer, although I suspect you won't be happy with the results.

---

Within the Marvel Universe, mortals and immortals are ranked using the official "[Power Grids](http://marvel.com/universe/OHOTMU:Power_Grids)".

There are some 50+ individual who score a 7 on this grid for 'intelligence' and are described as having "Omniscient" level intelligence.

This includes (among others) [Death](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Death_(Earth-616)), [The Living Tribunal](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Living_Tribunal_(Multiverse)), [Beyonder](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Beyonder_(Earth-616)), [Gaea](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Gaea_(Earth-616)), [Infinity](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity_(Entity)_(Earth-616)), [Oblivion](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Oblivion_(Earth-616)) and many, many other god-like beings (as well as the occasional genuine god).

By definition, two beings with omniscient intelligence cannot be smarter than each other which means it's a 50-way tie for first place.

---

If we exclude omniscients, we're left with mere mortals with "[Super-genius](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Super-Genius_Intelligence)" level intelligence. Again, ranking them is difficult because the metric is so limited, but we can see the usual suspects; Tony Stark, Reed Richards, Bruce Banner, Henry Pym, Dr Doom, etc etc

Comment: Never knew of the Power Grid. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, first part is wrong. Knowledge!=intelligence. Omniscent being simply knows things, doesn't make them necessarily smart capability wise (e.g., someone with photographic memory may learn every single product of all 3digit #s, but be fully unable to comprehend how to actually multiply multi-digit #s.

Comment: @dvk - Someone who is omniscient must, by definition, know the answer to every question since they know *everything*

Comment: @Richard - correct. I simply don't see that knowing the answers is relevant to being **smart** - it's being able to arrive at the answers that is. The end result may be the same, the mental process isn't

Comment: In World War Hulk Amadeus Cho is specifically described as being the 7th smartest person on the planet. Here's a discussion about the first 6. https://reddit.com/r/Marvel/comments/18igxj/okay_if_amadeus_cho_is_the_7th_smartest_humanwho/

Comment: @CreationEdge then maybe the issue here is the term person... Death is personified but nevertheless is not a person.